# Determine Insert mode in a Windows Form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to check the state of the Insert key in a C# Windows Form application.  Here is minimal code (which does not work; form with two RadioButtons):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Windows.Input;
// Also added PresentationCore and WindowsBase refereneces

namespace InsertModeDemo1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert))
                radioButtonInsert.Checked = true;
            else
                radioButtonOverstrike.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you include wpf related assemblies in winforms?

Comment: Keyboard and Key namespaces in those assemblies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `Control.IsKeyLocked` instead.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.Insert))
    radioButtonInsert.Checked = true;
  else
    radioButtonOverstrike.Checked = true;
}
```

*References: [Control.IsKeyLocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)*

**Note**

> The documentation says the method only works with <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd>, <kbd>NUM LOCK</kbd>, or <kbd>SCROLL LOCK</kbd> key only. But testing the method with `Keys.Insert` has proven that it also work for <kbd>INSERT</kbd> key.

Comment: Yes, I did. And have you try/ test the above code before voting my answer down? I have! and despite what the documentation said, it does work for `Keys.Insert`. And no, not a single `NotSupportedException` is raised...

Comment: Thank you for the comment though. I've updated the answer with a note for the _wrong_ documentation.

Comment: I've peeked through the implementation. `Insert` key is the exception for this rule. any other key will end up throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Listen to key change events, meaning, you'll need to keep track on the status yourself according to when the button is pressed.
2. Using win32 interop, take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/414e3e3d-2ce8-4d95-8846-0c42a157700e/insert-key-state) for example.

Comment: Option1 is not an option as cannot provide initial state